# Outlook Object Model get application signature

Tags: .net, vba, outlook

Is there a way to get a list of the signatures associated an Outlook application through the Outlook Object Model API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can easily access existing signatures without OOM - they are stored in `<CSIDL_APPDATA>\Microsoft\Signatures`. Note that "Signatures" folder name is localized on non-English versions of Windows.